# How do the Domain Controller validate the credentials for the Domain Member in the AD?

Tags: active-directory

I have some questions about how the Domain Controller validate the credentials for the Domain Member. I consider that the credential entered into login UI in the Domain Member by user will be sent to Domain Controller and validated. If the credential is valid, the user will be allowed to login the Domain Member and the credential will be cached in the Domain Member. If the Domain Member can not connect to the Domain Controller. The user can enter the latest valid password, which the user use to successfully login in the Domain Member at the last time.

The first question: If Domain Member can connect to Domain Controller,  Domain Member sent the credential enters by user to Domain Controller. Domain Controller will validate whether the credential is valid and Domain Member will not compare the entered credential with the cached credential in the local. Is that right?

The second question: Because of some situation, Domain Member will compare the entered credential with the cached credential in the local. The first one is that Domain Member can not connect to Domain Controller because of network question. Are there other situations that can be listed in the forum?

Comment: Stack Overflow is really just for programming questions. This question is a better fit for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), which is for server-administration questions.

Comment: But to answer your questions, 1. Yes, you are correct. 2. No, that's all. Either the computer can connect to the DC and validates the credentials, or it can't connect and accepts cached credentials. It will never use cached credentials if it can connect to the DC. There is some more reading here: [Cached and Stored Credentials Technical Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh994565(v%3Dws.11))